# MirrorWriterProcessor in Heritrix 3.2.0 active threads

Tags: java, heritrix

When im using the MirrorWriterProcessor Class i get only 1 active thread all the time because it wont accepts the de-outcomment properties for increasing max active threads for example. im no java programmer at all so if someone can help me i would appriciate it.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: eh how to get it running with maxium threads count with MirrorWriterProcessor.